# If and and only if ... otherwise

Tags: logic

Good day to everybody.

I have an algorithm that returns a tuple of two values, the tuple can be either (True, A) or (False, B). So, for example, a tuple cannot be (True, B).

In my proposition I have the following statement:

> Algorithm X returns (True, A) if and only if the condition Y is satisfied.

Unfortunately, I think that the statement is not very clear, because, if we take its inverse (which should be equivalent), it will look like this:

> Algorithm X does not return (True, A) if and only if the condition Y is not satisfied.

So, what does `does not return (True, A)` mean here? It could mean that it returns `(False, B)`, `(False, A)`, or `(True, B)` (or why even not `(True, C)` given that we do not really know what the negation of A means?).

To ameliorate the issue, I thought of rewriting the statement as follows:

> Algorithm X returns (True, A) if and only if the condition Y is satisfied (and (False,B) otherwise).

However, my statement then literally translates to the following two statements:

> If Algorithm X returns (True, A), then the condition Y is satisfied (and (False,B) otherwise).

and

> Algorithm X returns (True, A) if the condition Y is satisfied (and (False,B) otherwise).

Only the second of the sentences makes sense, and I could probably go with:

> Algorithm X returns (True, A) if the condition Y is satisfied, and (False,B) otherwise.

However, I would like to keep the `iff` part and also keep the `otherwise` part in parentheses, to save me some necessary space (because I use the sentence a lot and I will only use the parentheses the first time to specify what the negation of (True, A) is).

So, should I go with:

> Algorithm X returns (True, A) if and only if the condition Y is satisfied (and (False,B) otherwise).

Or is there any better more clear way I can write my statement and keep it compact for replication?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't a ‘tuple’  commonly called a pair?

Comment: yes, but I prefer this more generic term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the condition Y is satisfied, then Algorithm X returns (True,A).  Otherwise, it returns (False,B).

Attempts to use "if and only if" with this complicated idea are bound to cause confusion.

Comment: It seems that there is no way around it, so I will use: Algorithm X returns (True,A) if the condition Y is satisfied, and (False,B) otherwise.